# How to integrate Monolog in the Silex-WebProfiler?

Tags: php, symfony, silex, monolog

I am currently using the Silex Framework with Monolog as logging mechanism. I was able to successfully integrate the default Symfony WebProfiler in my project by using the following component - https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler (Silex-WebProfiler). It works, but unfortunately it cannot display the log messages from Monolog from its ***_profiler*** page. Does someone know how to solve that issue?

Here is my configuration if that's relevant at all:

```
use Silex\Provider;
...
//Monolog
$app->register(new Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
    'monolog.logfile' => __DIR__ . '/../log/development.log',
    'monolog.name'    => 'MyAppName'
));
...
// Web Profiler
if ($app['debug']) {
    $app->register(new Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
        'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../cache/profiler/',
        'profiler.mount_prefix' => '/_profiler', // this is the default
    ));    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was wondering this, too, and I found these lines in MonologServiceProvider.

```
if ($bridge = class_exists('Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger')) {
    $app['monolog.handler.debug'] = function () use ($app) {
        return new DebugHandler($app['monolog.level']);
    };
}
```

The logging to the Web Profiler is enabled by the Symfony Monolog Bridge component. I added this to my `composer.json`:

```
"symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3"
```

Now I see log entries in that panel of the web profiler. (It's probably a good idea to make sure the version of the monolog-bridge is in line with the versions of other Symfony components you've declared in your `composer.json`.)

Comment: PERFECT!!! The line "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3" in the composer did the job! Thank you very much!